# Magento Countries dropdown in customer details in admin section is empty but appearing fine on front end

Tags: magento

In magento,county names are not appearing in countries dropdown if I want to edit customer details from admin section.
So,I go through the code and found that there is function named getAllOptions() in core file which is as follows

```
public function getAllOptions()
    {
        if (!$this->_options) {
            $this->_options = $this->_factory->getResourceModel('directory/country_collection')
                ->loadByStore($this->getAttribute()->getStoreId())->toOptionArray();
        }
        return $this->_options;
    }
```

In this function if I remove `$this->getAttribute()->getStoreId()` from code,then countries appear in dropdown.
But I don't want to edit the core files.
I have checked countries settings in System->Configuration->General
and all countires are selected.
So can anyone suggest what is wrong with my admin section that this function is not working.

Answer (score 1):

Navigate to System->Configuration->General 
Inside that, Check the Current Configuration Scope.
For example if the customer is registered for store1, check the Countries Options for store1.

In the core_config_data table write following query to get more idea.

```
SELECT *
FROM `core_config_data`
WHERE `path` LIKE 'general/country/allow'
```

It will give you comma-separated list of countries that you have allowed for your store.

Comment: Thanks for reply.I have checked the database and it is displaying coutry code of all coutry for my store id.

Comment: And I have checked the general tab and it is displaying all countries as selected.

Comment: Which version of Magento CE are you using?

Comment: I am using Magento 1.9

Comment: It's a weird issue. Try logging result of $this->getAttribute()->getStoreId() or may be var_dump, what does it return. Debugging will help you solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I think your issue might be related to this one.
[Magento - Customer Address Country Dropdown Issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12055241/magento-customer-address-country-dropdown-issue/29977546#29977546)

The gist being; there is an entry in core_config_data with a value of null and a path of "general". Delete it and clear your cache.

Answer (score 0):

Please check the image for settings in configuration to fix the issues.

I had the same issue in admin customer address update country is empty, so i have fixed mu setting up like this.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/MCYrR.png